# ¿Cómo obtener los registros de un usuario que ya esta logueado en Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un carrito de compras en donde 2 usuarios distintos (user_id) han comprado diferentes productos:

[image: tabla carts de mi DataBase]

como pueden observar el user_id especifica cuantos productos tiene cada Usuario; es decir, 2 para el usuario con user_id=1 y 2 para el usuario con el user_id=2

pero cuando se obtienen los datos en la vista, se muestran los 4 registros de una vez | En esta imagen estoy logueado como Usuario con user_id=2

[image: tabla que muestra los productos agregados al carrito de compras]

este es mi CartController:

```
public function index()
{
    $cart_products = Cart::all();
    return view('pages.cart.index', compact('cart_products'));
}
```

Comment: Gracias, la relacion es belongsTo

Comment: entonces no tengo que llamar esos datos desde mi CartController, lo debo hacer desde mi ProductController, porque ya probe las opciones que me das y me da error. Ya agregue las relaciones en los modelos User y Cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la Documentación de Laravel, el formato sería el siguiente:

```
$users = App\User::where('active', 1)->get();
```

en donde 'active' sería mi campo 'user_id' y '1' corresponde al valor de mi user_id(1 ó 2, según la captura de la tabla en mi DataBase)

Aplicando lo anterior a mi caso en particular:

```
public function index()
{
   $cart_products = Cart::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
   return view('pages.cart.index', compact('cart_products'));
}
```

Referencia:
[Laravel Docs - Eloquents Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections)

Comment: Recuerda que si esta es la solución entonces marcarla como aceptada, de esa forma se entiende que esta es la solución

Answer (score 0):

> Te muestra los 4 registros por que la consulta que ejecutas al momento es sobre el modelo **`Cart`** y como tal no existe ahi alguna indicación para discriminar entre los registros basados en el usuario logueado.

Lo que puedes hacer dado que parece ser una relación *1:N* es crear en cada modelo las relaciones de esta forma:

Modelo User:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function carts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Cart:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Posterior para el caso de la consulta, donde buscas obtener solo los productos del usuario de la sesión actual:

```
$usuario = User::with('carts')->findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
```

- Con *eager loading* cargamos al modelo `User` con todas sus relaciones
- Con el *helper* `auth()` vamos a obtener la propiedad `id` del usuario que tiene la sesión actual

Y en la vista lo iterarías de esta manera:

```
    Productos del usuario con id: {{ $usuario->auth()->user()->id }}
    //iteramos con ayuda de la relación `carts` definida mas arriba los productos que ese usuario tiene actualmente vinculados o asociados
    @foreach($usuario->carts as $detalle)
        {{ $detalle->propiedadUnoModeloCart }}
        {{ $detalle->propiedadNModeloCart }}
    @endforeach
```

Sin elugar del `id` quieres el nombre del usuario entonces:

```
{{ $usuario->name }}
```

Para este caso no es necesario iterar al usuario pues es solo un objeto con los datos del actual, mientras que para los productos si por que al tener varios te esta regresando una colección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias**

- [Helper auth()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-auth)
- [Relación hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que realices una consulta con los modelos, la manera mas sencilla de obtener los productos del usuario que esta logeado actualmente es, utilizando Eloquent: Relationships de Laravel.

1° Declara la relacion de las tablas en el modelo User:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function carts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Cart', 'id', 'user_id');

        // 'App\Cart' -> Modelo de Eloquent del carrito
        // id -> Llave Primaria de tabla usuarios
        // user_id -> LLave foranea en tabla del carrito
    }
}
```

2° Imprimir los registros en la pagina con blade:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->carts as $product)
  {{ $product->name }}
  {{ $product->price }}
@endforeach

// 'Auth' -> es un helper de Laravel que te premite acceder a las propiedades del 
//  usuario logeado, eso incluye sus relaciones, claro esto solo funciona si estas 
//  usando el logeo de laravel.
```

Eloquent se encargara de imprimir solo los registros que cumplan con la relación.